# SharePoint JSON: Formatting List View with Empty Column and Date Value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm totally new to JSON formatting and need your help.

The SP list requires the following:

List formatting to show colors (green, yellow, red) if the **Request Completed Date is empty** as well as if the **Request Date exceeds 1 day, 7 days, and 8 days**.

Essentially, green = 1 day, 7 days = yellow, and more than 8 days = red.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON column formatting for this requirements. Use JSON like (considering today's date is 8/24/2022):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0 , '', if(@currentField + 691200000 < @now , 'ms-bgColor-red ms-fontColor-white', if(@currentField + 604800000 < @now , 'ms-bgColor-yellow ms-fontColor-white', if(@currentField + 86400000 < @now , 'ms-bgColor-green ms-fontColor-white', ''))))"
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**OR**:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0 , '', if(@currentField + 604800000 < @now , 'ms-bgColor-red ms-fontColor-white', if(@currentField + 518400000 < @now , 'ms-bgColor-yellow ms-fontColor-white', if(@currentField < @now , 'ms-bgColor-green ms-fontColor-white', ''))))"
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**References**:

1. [SharePoint column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)
2. [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)

---

You can enhance the JSON as per your further requirements, you can [check if date column is empty or not](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/) using expression `Number(@currentField) == 0`.

And you have to convert number of days to milliseconds to compare with current date (`@now`).

Example: 1 day = 1 x 24 x 60 x 60 x 1000 = 86400000

---

**Update from comments**:

Try using this JSON:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(Number(@currentField) == 0 , if([$RequestDate] + 604800000 < @now , 'ms-bgColor-red ms-fontColor-white', if([$RequestDate] + 518400000 < @now , 'ms-bgColor-yellow ms-fontColor-white', if([$RequestDate] < @now , 'ms-bgColor-green ms-fontColor-white', ''))), '')"
    }
}
```

Use correct **internal name** of Request Date column in place of `[$RequestDate]` in JSON expression in format: `[$InternalNameOfColumn]`. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

You have to apply this JSON formatting for "Request Completed Date" column.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!! :)

Comment: So sorry to bother but I'm just realizing the formatting doesn't work; the requirement is that if the Request Completed Date column is empty for 1 day, 7 days, or 8 days, then the column colors should change respectively in severity levels.

Comment: Do you mean: color code only if date field is empty for 1 day, 7 days, or 8 days from "Created" date?

Comment: Yep, exactly! Color code only if the Request Completed Date field has been empty for 1 day, 7 days, or 8 days from the Request Date.

Comment: Try expression like this: `=if(Number(@currentField) == 0 , if([$RequestDate] + 604800000 < @now , 'ms-bgColor-red ms-fontColor-white', if([$RequestDate] + 518400000 < @now , 'ms-bgColor-yellow ms-fontColor-white', if([$RequestDate] < @now , 'ms-bgColor-green ms-fontColor-white', ''))), '')`. Use correct **internal name** of Request Date column in place of `[$RequestDate]` in JSON expression.

Comment: Does this mean I would need to apply this JSON expression in the RequestDate column or the Completed column?

Comment: You need to apply this JSON on "Request Completed Date" column. check updated answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement, you could use the addDays() function to add days directly without counting seconds. It can also be compared to other columns, not just the current time.
For example below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(@currentField > addDays(Date([$A]), 1), '#00ff00', '')"
  }
}
```

[image: demo]